# xpath and scrapy in python 3.6 does not work

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to make this piece of code to work, so that I can scrapy some columns of a table from the website below: http://www.chiptiming.com.br/resultados/detalhes/2213609473

I have been trying to modify a lot of things in order to work, but no sucess, can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? I put the log as well. Thanks in advance.

ps: I have read many posts similar to mine, but I couldn't find what is the reason, sorry if this post is kind of repeated.

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector

from stack.items import StackItem

class StackSpider(Spider):
    name = "stack"
    allowed_domains = ["chiptiming.com.br"]
    start_urls = 
         ['http://www.chiptiming.com.br/resultados/detalhes/2213609473',]

def parse(self, response):
    products = response.xpath('//*[@id="uptPnlResultGrid"]/div/table//tr')
    # ignore the table header row
    for product in products[1:]:
        item = StackItem()
        item['Coloc'] = product.xpath('td[1]//text()').extract_first()
        item['NumPeito'] = product.xpath('td[2]//text()').extract_first()
        item['Nome'] = product.xpath('td[3]//text()').extract_first()
        yield item
```

> D:\Python\stack>python -m scrapy crawl stack -o items_corrida.json -t
>   json 2018-02-10 16:19:04 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.0 started
>   (bot: stack) 2018-02-10 16:19:04 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions:
>   lxml 4.1.0.0, libxml2 2.9.4, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.4.0, w3lib
>   1.19.0, Twisted 17.9.0, Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 15 2017, 03:27:45) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 17.2.0 (OpenSSL
>   1.0.2l  25 May 2017), cryptography 2.0.3, Platform Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0 2018-02-10 16:19:04 [scrapy.crawler] INFO:
>   Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'stack', 'FEED_FORMAT': 'json',
>   'FEED_URI': 'items_corrida.json', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'stack.spiders',
>   'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['stack.spiders']}
>   2018-02-10 16:19:04 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
>   ['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats', 
>   'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole', 
>   'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter', 
>   'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats'] 2018-02-10 16:19:04
>   [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
>   ['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats'] 2018-02-10
>   16:19:04 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
>   ['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware'] 2018-02-10 16:19:04
>   [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: [] 2018-02-10
>   16:19:04 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened 2018-02-10 16:19:04
>   [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min),
>   scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min) 2018-02-10 16:19:04
>   [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on
>   127.0.0.1:6024 2018-02-10 16:19:04 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to
>   http://www.chiptiming.com.br/404.aspx> from http://www.chiptiming.com.br/robots.txt> 2018-02-10 16:19:04
>   [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) http://www.chiptiming.com.br/404.aspx> (referer: None) 2018-02-10
>   16:19:04 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) http://www.chiptiming.com.br/resultados/detalhes/2213609473> (referer:
>   None) 2018-02-10 16:19:04 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider
>   (finished) 2018-02-10 16:19:04 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping
>   Scrapy stats: {'downloader/request_bytes': 880, 
>   'downloader/request_count': 3,  'downloader/request_method_count/GET':
>   3,  'downloader/response_bytes': 17534,  'downloader/response_count':
>   3,  'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2, 
>   'downloader/response_status_count/302': 1,  'finish_reason':
>   'finished',  'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 10, 18, 19, 4,
>   768123),  'log_count/DEBUG': 4,  'log_count/INFO': 7, 
>   'response_received_count': 2,  'scheduler/dequeued': 1, 
>   'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,  'scheduler/enqueued': 1, 
>   'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,  'start_time': datetime.datetime(2018,
>   2, 10, 18, 19, 4, 319337)} 2018-02-10 16:19:04 [scrapy.core.engine]
>   INFO: Spider closed (finished)

Comment: Please provide desired output and what you are currently getting

Comment: There is no information your want inside source HTML code (you can check it with `Ctrl+U` in your browser). It's loaded through AJAX call (`POST` to http://www.chiptiming.com.br/resultados/detalhes/2213609473 )

Comment: Is there a way of get that information out of the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and only got an empty products from this line:

`products = response.xpath('//*[@id="uptPnlResultGrid"]/div/table//tr')`

I think it's dynamic website, try splash.